# Some questions about bazel concept

Tags: bazel

I am learning Bazel and confused by many basic concepts.

```
    load("//bazel/rules:build_tools.bzl", "build_tools_deps")
    build_tools_deps()      //build_tools_deps is macro or rules?

    load("@bazel_gazelle//:deps.bzl", "gazelle_dependencies")
    gazelle_dependencies()  //what about the @ mean exactly? where is the bazel_gazelle ?
    native.new_git_repository(...) //what about the native mean?
```

What definition is called a function? what definition is a rule?

Answer (score 6):

A **macro** is a regular Starlark function that wraps (and expands to) rules.

```
def my_macro(name = ..., ...):
    native.cc_library(...)
    android_library(...)
    native.genrule(...)
```

Think of macros as a way to chain and group several rules together, which allows you to pipe the output of some rules into the input of others. At this level, you don't think about how a rule is implemented, but what kinds of inputs and outputs they are associated with.

On the other hand, a **rule's** **declaration** is done using the `rule()` function. `cc_library`, `android_library` and `genrule` are all rules. The **rule** **implementation** is abstracted in a regular function that accepts a single parameter for the rule context ([`ctx`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/ctx.html)).

```
my_rule = rule(
  attrs = { ... },
  implementation = _my_rule_impl,
)

def _my_rule_impl(ctx):
  outfile = ctx.actions.declare_file(...)
  ctx.actions.run(...)
  return [DefaultInfo(files = depset([outfile]))]
```

Think of actions as a way to chain and group several command lines together, which works at the level of individual files and running your executables to transform them (`ctx.actions.run` with `exectuable`, `args`, `inputs` and `outputs` arguments). Within a rule implementation, you can extract information from rule attributes (`ctx.attr`), or from dependencies through providers (e.g. `ctx.attr.deps[0][DefaultInfo].files`)

Note that rules can only be called in BUILD files, not WORKSPACE files.

**`@` is the notation for a repository namespace.** `@bazel_gazelle` is an external repository fetched in the WORKSPACE by a **repository rule** (not a regular rule), typically `http_archive` or `git_repository`. This repository rule can also be called from a macro, like `my_macro` above or `build_tools_deps` in your example.

`native.<rule name>` means that the rule is implemented in Java within Bazel and built into the binary, and not in Starlark.

Comment: Thank you, I want to know when should use native.cc_library and when should use cc_library?

Comment: `native.cc_library` is used in `bzl` files. In a `BUILD` file, using `cc_library` directly implies that you are using the built-in rule.